# Api platoform ManyToMany unidirectional relation with JoinTable error: attribute must be an array string given

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony5

So I have two entites :
`NextInfusionMashStepWithoutGrainAdjunct`

```
// [...]
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=WaterGrainRatio::class)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="next_infusion_mash_step_without_grain_adjunct_water_grain_ratio",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="next_infusion_mash_step_without_grain_adjunct_water_grain_ratio_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="water_grain_ratio_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
     * )
     * @Groups("post:nextInfusionStepWithoutGrainAdjunct")
     */
    private ?WaterGrainRatio $waterGrainRatioId;
//[...]
```

And `WaterGrainRatio`

```
//[...]
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;
//[...]
```

I have added an WaterGrainRatioId with id: 1

And when I try to add a NextInfusionStepWithoutGrainAdjunct with postman with this body:

```
{
  "waterGrainRatioId": "/dashboard/water_grain_ratios/1",
  "...": "..."
}
```

I got this error:  `"The type of the \"waterGrainRatioId\" attribute must be \"array\", \"string\" given.",`

I can't figure out why The IRI is not understood and why it needs an array.

What I tried:
`#[ApiProperty(readableLink: false, writableLink: false)]` but it did not works.

EDIT: I figure it out with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547669/symfony-api-platform-many-to-many-relationship-only-working-in-one-way), I just have to pass an array of IRI like this:

```
"waterGrainRatioId": [
    "/dashboard/water_grain_ratios/1",
    "/dashboard/water_grain_ratios/2"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my edit I solve my problem by passing an array of IRIs:

```
"waterGrainRatioId": [
    "/dashboard/water_grain_ratios/1",
    "/dashboard/water_grain_ratios/2"
]
```